# Page load out animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animations

Hi guys I have a question about running an animation whenever a user clicks a link to a different webpage. The problem is that I don't know how to set a dynamic Window.location. Currently my code looks like this

```
$('.url').click(function(){
$('.page-load-animation').addClass('page-load-out');
  setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "www.bayron.nl/recepten-toevoegen-template.html";
    }, 2000);
});
```

This does what I want but it only redirects to a specified webpage. How can I make the URL dynamic so that the users will be redirected to the page of the link that they clicked?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you want to navigate to other page without refresh, if that's the question then you should check out history.pushState

Comment: So the problem you're having is that the URL is hard coded, but you want to use the url that the clicked link points to? If so `this.href` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @katniss.everbean Thanks! your answer worked!

Answer (score 1):

@katniss.everbean gave me the answer. If anyone out there is searching for the quick answer, this is what my code looks like. And it works

```
    $('.url').click(function(){

    var linkLocation = this.href;

    $('.page-load-animation').addClass('page-load-out');
  setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = linkLocation;
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

html part

```
 <div class="url" link="http://www.bayron.nl/recepten-toevoegen-template.html">test page</div>
 <div class="url" link="http://www.bayron.nl/recepten-toevoegen-templatepage2.html">test page2</div>
```

javascript part

```
$('.url').click(function(){
url = $(this).attr("link")
$('.page-load-animation').addClass('page-load-out');
  setTimeout(function() {

        window.location.href =url;
    }, 2000);
});
```

is this what you want

Comment: Katniss.everbean's answer did it for me. But thanks for the help!